# Почему вызов не безопасной функции из DLL всё крашит

Tags: c#, winapi

Скажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так при вызове функции? :

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate IntPtr CreateSemaphore(uint dwDesiredAccess, long lInitialCount, long lMaximumCount, string lpName);


IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"kernel32.dll");
IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "CreateSemaphoreA");
CreateSemaphore createSemaphore = (CreateSemaphore)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(CreateSemaphore));
IntPtr theResult = createSemaphore(0,2,2,"qwerty");
```

Так же пробовал через PInvoke делать:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern HANDLE CreateSemaphore(uint dwDesiredAccess, long lInitialCount, long lMaximumCount, string lpName);

IntPtr result = winapi.CreateSemaphore(0,0,3,"qwerty");
```

> Ошибка о том что память могла быть изменена и т.д., но запускаю например CreateMutex (public static extern IntPtr CreateMutex(IntPtr lpMutexAttributes, bool bInitialOwner, string lpName)) всё отлично ((((

UPD:

```
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall,CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private delegate IntPtr CreateSemaphore(IntPtr dwDesiredAccess, long lInitialCount, long lMaximumCount, string lpName);

        IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"kernel32.dll");
        IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "CreateSemaphoreA");
        CreateSemaphore createSemaphore = (CreateSemaphore)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(CreateSemaphore));
        IntPtr theResult = createSemaphore(new IntPtr(),2,2,"qwerty");
```

Comment: 1) CallingConvention.StdCall 2) uint dwDesiredAccess -> IntPtr lpSemaphoreAttributes 3) CharSet = CharSet.Ansi

Comment: @Vasek исправил, но увы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип LONG в заголовках Windows - [это 32-битное целое](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types). Добавим к этому исправления от @Vasek, получаем:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
private delegate IntPtr CreateSemaphore(IntPtr lpSemaphoreAttributes, int lInitialCount, int lMaximumCount, string lpName);
```

Comment: Огромнейшее тебе спасибо и @vasek тоже :3